# how to go same view controller when button pressed in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alert, viewcontroller

I am developing a login app, and I have some queries. if the login button is pressed, whatever text is in that textfield should be displayed in next view controller - like username and password. So I used segues to take values to next view Controller.

If both text field values are null and then press login button means,I display an alert to fill both textfields. When pressing an OK button in alert the program AUTOMATICALLY  goes to second controller. I don't know how to go same view controller when button pressed. kindly help me.

My code:

```
   -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue )segue sender:(id)sender
{ 
    second *transferViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    if ([txt1.text isEqualToString:@"" || txt2.text isEqualToString:@"" ]) 
    { 
      UIAlertView * mes=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!!!!!!" message:@"This is the Iphone app" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
      [mes show]; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: show ur alert view delegate method and where u called the OK button in alert --  show the code

Comment: -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    
    second *transferViewController = [segue destinationViewController];                                                                                                                     if ([txt1.text isEqualToString:@"" || txt2.text isEqualToString:@"" ]) {
        UIAlertView* mes=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!!!!!!"                                                   message:@"This is the Iphone app" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];       
       [mes show];
        } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need of `prepareForSegue`

```
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue )segue sender:(id)sender

  { second *transferViewController = [segue destinationViewController]; 

    }
```

change your function into `IBAction` method

```
  -(IBAction)login:(id)sender
  {

     if ([txt1.text isEqualToString:@"" || txt2.text isEqualToString:@"" ]) 
     { 
       UIAlertView *mes=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Empty Fields !!!" message:@"enter the user details" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil]; 
     [mes show];

    }

   else

    {

        // both textfield are filled and validated
          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"your segue name of secondVC" sender:sender]; 
        }
     }
```

Comment: need help i surely hope with u

Comment: - (IBAction)track:(UIButton )sender { second *secondViewController = [[second alloc] init]; if(a == 1) { secondViewController.data = @"wow"; [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"first" sender:sender]; } else { UIAlertView mes=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!!!!!!" message:@"This is the Iphone app" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil]; [mes show]; } }. Declared data as STRING in secondViewController. now,, if condition satisfy means,, IF block is executing,, it moving to next controller,, but unable to ADD NEW VALUE to Secondviewcontroller's LABEL. Help me

Comment: @GopiKrish - if u don't mine can u send ur project in mail id : karthik.saral@gmail.com -- i solve ur issue

Comment: s Karthick... i ll do imm.

Comment: Hi Karthik,,, check ur Mail

Comment: kindly intimate me,,,,, atfr checking mail.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do it. One of the nicer ways to do this is by connecting two scenes in a storyboard using a segue that is not attached to an action. After that, you can programmatically trigger the segue inside your view controller. The way you do this is by control-dragging from the file owner icon at the bottom of the storyboard scene to the destination scene.

A popup will appear that will ask for an option in “Manual Segue”; pick “Push” as the type. Tap on the little square and make sure you’re in the Attributes Inspector. Give it an identifier which you will use to refer to it in code. Next, you are going to trigger the segue using a button(or can u can use the AlertView delegate ) .That have the selector like “buttonAction”. This is the function that will be called if you press the button.this function to trigger the segue and go to the destination scene. So a void() method for that button and within that method and call the segue like this:

```
-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender{
 if(textfield.text.length!=0){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueName" sender:sender];
  }
 else{
     alert!!
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aiden,, but wen it is in null,, i kept an alert,, if v pressed OK  button,, y it is going to second? it should be stop in same page. i dnt knw. kindly help me.

Comment: Hi Gopi, Its happening because you have connect the second scene to the buttonAction from the InterfaceBuilder. You should not do that, instead create a segue without action in InterfaceBuilder and in code you trigger the segue like Aiden explained in his answer.

Comment: Ya Krrish...!!! I have given button action using storyboard. i ll delete it and i ll check.

Comment: @GopiKrish You have to wire the segue from the view controller it self not from the Button

Comment: - (IBAction)track:(UIButton *)sender {
    second *secondViewController = [[second alloc] init];
    
    if(a == 1) {
                secondViewController.lbl3.text = @"wow";
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"first" sender:sender];
        
           }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView* mes=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!!!!!!"
                                                    message:@"This is the Iphone app" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        
        [mes show];

    }
}

Comment: Hi Aiden,,, here for track button i didn't give action,, by ur advice i added segue directly to view controller,, now if i press that track button,, else condition is working. IF is not working. same time,, i declared a==1 only.

Comment: but i unable to add new value in second view controller's label. kindly help me.

Comment: @GopiKrish what is a==1 and what the result u need

Comment: just variable i ve declared. a=1.

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if ([txt1.text isEqualToString:@"" || txt2.text isEqualToString:@"" ])
    {
        UIAlertView * mes=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!!!!!!" message:@"This is the Iphone app" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [mes show];
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yoursegueID" sender:nil]; // 
    }

}



- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{

    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yoursegueID" sender:nil];
    }
}
```

also set `UIAlertViewDelegate`

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> //in which you used `UIAlertView`
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing the method `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:`  This method returns a BOOL that indicates whether the segue should proceed -

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{ 

  BOOL ret=YES:

  if ([txt1.text isEqualToString:@"" || txt2.text isEqualToString:@"" ]) 
  { 
    UIAlertView * mes=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!!!!!!" message:@"This is the Iphone app" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [mes show]; 
    ret=NO;
  } 

  return ret;
}
```